# How to count the number of question mark in Numbers?

Tags: numbers, wildcard

I want to count how many rows contains '?' in a column in Numbers(MacOS) .

I use `COUNTIF(COLUMN1, "=?")`.

However, '?' is a wildcard in Numbers, which means any cell contains exact one character will be counted by this formula.

I also tried to use `"=\?"` but didn't work here.

Example:

[image]

`COUNTIF(COLUMN1, "=?")`=3

**But I want just count the number of '?', so the result should be 2**

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution myself.

Using '~' solve the problem:

```
COUNTIF(COLUMN1, "=~?")
```